# How to get "3 months of Apple TV+ for free" offer back?

Tags: macbook-pro, appletv

We bought a new MacBook Pro for my wife around a month ago and there was this message about "3 months of Apple TV+ for free" somewhere in settings, but it has disappeared recently. Is there any way to get it back?

[Here](https://www.apple.com/promo/pdf/EN_US_ATV+_Promo_TandCs.pdf) it says

> Offer is available for eligible devices for a limited time only.

but I'm not sure if it actually means, you have to redeem it in X days or it is too late.

Comment: Anecdotally - I have no hard citation to back this up. Yup, if you don't redeem it, it disappears. We had similar in that we bought two Apple products several months apart. Our intention was to hold out on the second offer until the first expired - but the second offer's start point expired [vanished] before the first's end-point.

Comment: Policies may be different depending on which country you reside in, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official support answer: The offer for this MacBook has expired and there is no way to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

The offer is still available for me when I click on the tv+ tab in the TV.app.

I also received emails from Apple 'reminding' me of the offer. (It's been more than 3 months since I purchased an Apple product...)

The link in the email takes you to a page where you can check your eligibility:

http://apple.co/offertvp0121

Comment: That confirms my guess from the comment above, there's no mention of the second offer any more. The first has now expired.